# How to update a form reset "baseline state" after an Ajax update

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a form that has a cancel / reset. The updating is done with Ajax. If I submit a (successful) update, then make an additional change to the check boxes but then choose cancel (read: reset), the reset goes all the way back to the original values. Mind you, the DB isn't being updated (due to not submitting) but what displays is inaccurate and misleading.

How do I update the "baseline state" (?) of the form so the cancel / reset goes back to the new version of the form values.

Comment: Show us some code. It is almost impossible to give valid answer if we don't see what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

I would perform an additional AJAX call to retrieve the current values from the database to reset the values.  You can design the application to use the same lookup on page load and when reset is clicked.

An additional option would be to store off the values from the last save in [HTML5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) on each form field.  When reset is clicked you'd could re-populate the values based on the data attribute.  For example.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="jim" data-last-value="joe" />

/* JS - Do this on reset. */ 
$('[data-last-value]').each(function() {
    var lastValue = $(this).attr('data-last-value');  
    $(this).val(lastValue);
});
```